# Error: final de datos inesperado al hacer JSON.parse

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo función JavaScript que mediante AJAX envía al servidor con PHP una consulta. Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Ésta es la función en JavaScript:

```
function buscaCliente(){
var opcion = $("#opcionBuscaC").val();
var variable=$('#variableBusca').val();
if(opcion==='0'){
}
if(opcion==='1'){
    location.reload();
}
if(opcion==='2'){//ruc
    var datos={'bandera':'busca','identificacion':variable, 'nombre':'vacio'};
    var datosConver=JSON.stringify(datos);
    //funEnvio(datosConver);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'funcionesCliente.php',
        data:{parametros:datosConver},
        error: function(){alert ('Error en la llamada Ajax');},
        success: function(dato){
            if(dato==='NO DATOS'){
                alert('No se encontraron registros');
                $('tbody').remove();
            }else{
                var datos = $.parseJSON(dato);
                $('tbody').remove();
                $('#clienteReporte').append('<tbody>');
                $.each(datos, function(i,item){
                    var tr= $('<tr>').append(
                                $('<td>').text(i),
                                $('<td>').text(item.id),
                                $('<td>').text(item.identificacion),
                                $('<td>').text(item.razonsocial),
                                $('<td>').text(item.direccion),
                                $('<td>').text(item.telefono),
                                $('<td>').text(item.celular),
                                $('<td>').text(item.email),
                                $('<td>').append($('<a href="#">').text('VER')),
                                );
                            $('tbody').append(tr);                  
                });
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Éste es el PHP:

```
    $cliente= json_decode($_POST['parametros']);
$bandera=$cliente->{'bandera'};

switch ($bandera){
case 'ingresa': insertaCliente($conexion, $cliente);
    break;
case 'lista': buscaCliente($conexion, $cliente);
    break;
}

//FUNCION LISTAR CLIENTE
    function buscaCliente($conexion,$cliente) {
        $identificacion=$cliente->{'identificacion'};
        $nombre=$cliente->{'nombre'};
        $consulta= "CALL PA_buscacliente('$identificacion','$nombre');";
        $resultado= mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)==0){
            echo 'NO DATOS';
        }else{
            while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $contenedor[] = $filas;
        }
                  echo json_encode($contenedor,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        }

    }
```

Y éste es el JSON que se forma en JavaScript:

```
 {
    "0": {
        "id": "1",
        "identificacion": "0123456789",
        "razonsocial": "NOMBRE RAZON SOCIAL",
        "direccion": "DIRECCION",
        "telefono": "012345678",
        "celular": "1234567890",
        "email": "mi@email.com",
        "descripcion": "RUC"
    }
 }
```

> NOTA: tengo el mismo código  en otro archivo y funciona correctamente (solamente que no está dentro de una función).

Comment: Podrias incluir el resultado de tu codigo php `echo json_encode($contenedor,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`? Pareciera que el JSON que este formando tenga un formato incorrecto.

Comment: Entendido. Podrias colocar en tu pregunta el resultado de imprimir a consola el resutlado de la llamada AJAX: `console.log(dato)`? Justo antes de `if(dato==='NO DATOS'){`

Comment: gracias cavpollo por tu atencion, pero ya encontre la respuesta, el valor de la variable bandera no era el mismo en el javascript con el php de ahi surge el problema, la funcion $.parseJSON(); parece que al recibir un valor nulo o vacio da el error mencionado.

Comment: A mi me pasó lo mismo, en mi caso fue porque uno de los archivos que se intentaban cargar llevan el símbolo º. Lo renombré y se arregló.

Comment: @Felix si encontraste una respuesta, por favor, escríbela en la sección de respuestas para que la pregunta esté completa. Lee [ask] y [answer] para más información.